# How to set cookie in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend, phtml, cookie, attribute-value

I need to set a value to the cookie in a phtml file and I need to get it's value in another phtml file.

Is it possible to set and get the values using jQuery?

Answer (score 9):

**Create Cookie**

We will be creating a test controller to create

> app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/Controller/Cookie/Addcookie.php

```
<?php
namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Controller\Cookie;
class Addcookie extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
const COOKIE_NAME = 'test';
const COOKIE_DURATION = 86400; // lifetime in seconds
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
*/
protected $_cookieManager;
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
*/
protected $_cookieMetadataFactory;
/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
* @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
*/
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
)
{
     $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
     $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
     parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
     $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
         ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
         ->setDuration(self::COOKIE_DURATION);
     $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
         self::COOKIE_NAME,
         'YOUR COOKIE VALUE',
         $metadata
     );
     echo('Create Cookie');
}
}
```

**Read Cookie**

We will create a Readcookie.php controller to read cookie

> app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/Controller/Cookie

```
<?php
namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Controller\Cookie;
class Readcookie extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
*/
protected $_cookieManager;
/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
*/
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
)
{
     $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
     parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
     $cookieValue = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie(\[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Controller\Cookie\Addcookie::COOKIE_NAME);
     echo($cookieValue);
}
}
```

**Delete Cookie**

We will create a Deletecookie.php controller to create cookie

> app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/Controller/Cookie

```
<?php
namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Controller\Cookie;
class Deletecookie extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
*/
protected $_cookieManager;
/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
*/
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
)
{
     $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
     parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
     $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie(
         \[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Controller\Cookie\Addcookie::COOKIE_NAME
     );
     echo('DELETED');
}
}
```

The 3 steps I mention above is the shortest process for you to Use Cookie in Magento 2. With this guide, you can manage the Cookie in Magento 2 easily.

Comment: Hello it's not working on magento2.3 versions

Comment: In the `metadata` you need to specify both path and domain. for example : ```$this->_cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration(self::COOKIE_DURATION)
            ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain());```

Answer (score 6):

### Set the cookies

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/cookies'
    ], function ($) {
       $.cookie('cookie_name', 'value', { path: '/' });//Set the cookies
    });
</script>
```

> If you want to get the value from another page, notice the **path** setting `{ path: '/' }`!
>
> Because **cookies are only accessible to the specified path and any subpaths**, more discussion about this you could see here [Cookie path and its accessibility to subfolder pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576535/cookie-path-and-its-accessibility-to-subfolder-pages).

### Get the cookies

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/cookies'
    ], function ($) {
        var temp = $.cookie('cookie_name');//Get the cookies
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    require(
        [ 'jquery'],function($){
            //set cookie
            $.cookie('customname', 'customvalue', { expires: 365, path: '/' });

            //get cookie
            getCookieValue(customname)
        });

        function getCookieValue(cookiename) {
                var name = cookiename + "=";
                var cookieSplit = document.cookie.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i <cookieSplit.length; i++) {
                    var a = cookieSplit[i];
                    while (a.charAt(0)==' ') {
                        a = a.substring(1);
                    }
                    if (a.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                        return a.substring(name.length,a.length);
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }
</script>
```

Comment: i need to get the cookie value in another phtml page. how it gets?

Comment: You can same as above just remove $.cookie() line

Comment: Have you try with above code?

Comment: yeah, i didn't get the answer.

Comment: whats the issue have you faced?

Comment: How can I set cookie when user goes to category page and every time visit of category page update category id in cookie value?